# Should Ubuntu work with Dell Dimension 8200?

Tags: 11.10, dell, 32-bit

I want to install Ubuntu on a Dell Dimension 8200 but it won't install. It starts booting ISOLINUX from CD but one row of installation is all I get, then it's like either the CD is broken or that for some unexplained other reason it won't install. Should it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this trick. Insert the Ubuntu CD and start your computer as usual, and then, when you see the Ubuntu logo, press arrow up and down and it should appear a menu asking to try or install Ubuntu. Choose to try it to verify if everything works. If this menu doesn't appear, maybe your CD is broken or there are some problem in starting the Ubuntu live Cd.

Comment: I never see an ubuntu logo since the graphics doesn't load. It can't load from CD any more than `ISOLINUX 4.04 20110518 ETCD...` and then `Loading bootlogo...` and then nothing happens. I don't know what you mean by "start your computer as usual" - boot from CD or boot my old MS-Windows?